# como auto seleccionar y bloquear un select automaticamente apartir de la seleccion de otro select php mysql js

Tags: php, mysql

codigo del select princiapal

Estado laboral 


">

codigo del select secuandario

Regimen

```
                <select name="regimen" id="regimen" class="select-css" style="width:190px;">
                    <option value=" 0">Seleccione</option>
                    <?php  
         
                         $conf = new Configuracion();
                             $conf->conectarBD();                                                                             
                             $consulta = "SELECT idregimen,regimen FROM regimen";
                             $rst1 = $conf->consulta($consulta);
                              for($i = 0; $i < count($rst1); $i++)
                         {                                                   
                            echo '<option value="'.$rst1[$i]["idregimen"].'">'.$rst1[$i]["regimen"].'</option>';                                                    
                             }
                            $conf->desconectarDB();
                             ?>
                </select>
```

lo que quiero es que si en el select primero selecciono la opcion 1 que es empleado entonces que autoseleccione la opcion 2 del segundo select y que bloquee para que el usuario no pueda seleccionar la otra opcion y si el usuario selecciona la opcion 2 en el primer select que no pase nada que el pueda seleccionar cualquiera de las dos opciones como podria hacer eso?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has intentado hasta el momento para intentar dar con la solución?

Comment: en realidad eliminar el otro option del select y con una funcion en js poner el select disabled o algo asi pero no me funciona